# Customization of the section title in the Copenhagen theme

Tags: beamer, formatting

I'm using the Copenhagen template to create a beamer-style latex presentation. However, I am unable to break the section title line so that the entire text can be seen. I would like to know how I could solve this problem. Perhaps a solution would be to increase this bar in black and decrease the bar in green, however I don't know how to do that.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probably easiest way to prevent long section headings from being cut off is to use the optional argument of the section command in order to provide a shortened version of the section headings for the use in the header. The table of contents will still show the longer version of the section's heading.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{copenhagen}

\begin{document}
\section{section heading}
\section[shortened section heading]{a very very long heading that would get cut off inside of a narrower beamercolorbox}
\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

If you insist on showing the full section title in the header while at the same time making sure, the black box does take up more than 50%  of the frame's width, you may want to take a look at the following suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{copenhagen}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{custom split theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.75\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{section heading}
\section{a very very long heading that would get cut off inside of a narrower beamercolorbox}
\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Side note: Inside of the `copenhagen` theme, which internally uses the `split` outer theme, the left box in the header usually contains the section headings, while the right box contains subsection headings. Since I significantly reduced the width of the right box, it now no longer contains subsection headings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would it be possible to insert a line break in a long title?

Answer (score 3):

Here I do two things out of the ordinary.  I create a placeholder `\section` to reserve a blank line.  Then, I use a `\Longstack` to create the actual section title taking up two lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usetheme{copenhagen}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\section{section heading}
\begin{frame}
contents section heading
\end{frame}
\section{~}% PLACEHOLDER
\section{\Longstack[r]{a very very long heading that would get cut off inside
  \\ of a narrower beamercolorbox}}
\begin{frame}
contents long title
\end{frame}
\section{Next}
\begin{frame}
contents Next
\end{frame}
\section{Last}
\begin{frame}
contents Last
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]